# help configuring openid for enki blog in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openid, blogs

I am trying to set up a blog using Enki. There is a config file here: http://github.com/xaviershay/enki/blob/master/config/enki.yml

Which I don't understand. I signed up for myopenID and replaced my username in the delegate, but I don't understand what goes under "open_id" - is it just my URL? I'm just not sure what's going on, or what name I should put in the admin page at all (is it the username at myopenID?).

I may have it all right, but I keep getting "OpenID server not found" so something is going wrong on both my local and remote server.

Comment: amen brother. i seriously thought it was me that was the only one who didn't understand how to do this.  Thanks for writing this question up.  "just go to /admin" it says... pfft right.

Comment: I don't see how this offers any security protection. if someone knows your yourmyopenidname.myopenid.com then they could go to /admin and just enter it and get in. No password?

Comment: uh, i was wrong,  openid had somehow figured out who i was so when I entered the path, it automatically logged me in with asking for password!  in another browser it asks for the password.

Comment: If anyone wanted to submit a pull request improving the documentation that'd be much appreciated. I think I'm too familiar with OpenID to be able to write a beginner friendly intro. [I'm the author of enki.]

Answer (score 4):

I struggled a bit with this, and then ended up solving it.

Steps:

1. Get a myopenid.com open id (this is easiest, though if you know what you are doing with, say, Google's OpenID then you can do that too)
2. Comment out the last two lines of the config/enki.yml (server: http://www... & delegate: http://...)
3. Comment out the lines after "open_id:" but NOT the line that says "open_id_delegation:"
4. Right underneath "open_id:" write "      - http://*yourmyopenidname*.myopenid.com"
5. Save then goto /admin, enter *yourmyopenidname*.myopenid.com in the "Stop! Who are you?" box

This should get you straighted out. Good luck!

Comment: I don't see how this offers any security protection. If someone knows your yourmyopenidname.myopenid.com then they could put that in the box and access your blog. There's no password to get into the blog.

Comment: i was wrong, openid had somehow figured out who i was so when I entered the path, it automatically logged me in with asking for password! in another browser it asks for the password.